# Android instrumentation ListView click

Tags: android, instrumentation

I have a ListView in my activity. When i click on an item in the ListView, i call an intent and start a new Activity. I have set up my test cases, and obtained a reference for my ListView. How do i now simulate the user clicking on a ListView row ? Below is my code for my test case which passes correctly

```
@SmallTest
    public void testAdapter(){
        childActivity=startActivity(mStartIntent, null, null);
        TextView t2=(TextView) childActivity.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        secondListView=(ListView)childActivity.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        assertNotNull(secondListView);
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnCreate(childActivity, null);
        getInstrumentation().callActivityOnResume(childActivity);
        assertEquals(t2.getText(), text);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> testAdapter=(ArrayAdapter<String>) secondListView.getAdapter();
        assertFalse(testAdapter.isEmpty());


    }
```

Comment: Consider using Robotium for testing your Activity's UI.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `OnItemClickListener`:

```
secondListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View searchListV, int position, long id)
                {
                    //Do stuff here
                }
            });
```

**Edit:**

To programmatically click, use the following:

```
secondListView.performItemClick(view, position, id);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to programatically click on an item of the ListView.

Comment: yes, i want to simulate a user clicking on various rows in the ListView.

Comment: Sorry, see my edit. Pass in the listView, postion you want to click and the id if required.

Answer (score 0):

There's more detailed code here:
[Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) and in the SpinnerTest sample app.